# Override resolved property type with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

With AutoMapper, can I override the resolved type for a property? For example, given these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Value { get; set; }
}

public class Child { ... }
public class DerivedChild : Child { ... }
```

Can I configure AutoMapper to automap the `Child Value` property with a `DerivedChild` instance? The hypothetical mapping would look something like this:

```
map.CreateMap<ChildEntity, DerivedChild>();
map.CreateMap<ParentEntity, Parent>()
   .ForMember(p => p.Value, p => p.UseDestinationType<DerivedChild>());
```

(I'm [projecting from LINQ entities](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions). The closest I could find is using a [custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters), but it looks like I'd need to override the *entire* mapping.)

Comment: Can you show the `ParentEntity` class?

Comment: @YacoubMassad let's assume `ParentEntity` looks just like `Parent` (with a `ChildEntity Value` property), so we can automap it by convention. The actual models are more complicated and use mapping expressions, but not in a way that affects the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
map.CreateMap<ChildEntity, DerivedChild>();

map.CreateMap<ParentEntity, Parent>()
    .ForMember(
        x => x.Value,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
            rr => map.Map<DerivedChild>(((ParentEntity)rr.Context.SourceValue).Value)));
```

`ResolveUsing` allows to specify custom logic for mapping the value.

The custom logic that is used here is actually calling `map.Map` to map to `DerivedChild`.

Comment: I am glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

You may re-assign new object manually after mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentEntity, Parent>()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Value =  new DerivedChild(){...});
```

or even re-map it:

```
   .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Value = Mapper.Map<DerivedChild>(dest.Value));
```